# Created self-signed openssl certificate on ubuntu with sudo, now apache fails to recognize

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

Hi I am on a linux instance server running ubuntu 14.04. I have a website setup which I later realised that needs https rather than just http. So to start with I created a self-signed certificate. by passing the command below

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

After completing all the steps still my I cant access my website when I prepend https:// and only works on http://. I have a feeling that while creating the key using sudo created as a root and www-data doesn't recognize it. I checked my ssl error logs and it keeps repeating these two things.

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 29081] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[ssl:warn] [pid 29081] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 52.24.182.161:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I am stuck at this point, I just want to use a self-signed certificate and my site to work using https://

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 52.24.182.161
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website-ssl-access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

My output of `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt`

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 17752245544736062623 (0xf65ca5447b80fc9f)
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=GB, ST=London, L=London city, O=Hom, OU=Digital, CN=sgurung
    Validity
        Not Before: Oct 18 15:47:58 2016 GMT
        Not After : Oct 18 15:47:58 2017 GMT
    Subject: C=GB, ST=London, L=London city, O=Hom, OU=Digital, CN=sgurung
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:96:e5:4f:f9:c6:fc:4c:62:7d:ef:a1:64:1d:9a:
                1a:79:c2:bb:1d:38:54:88:c3:c8:b6:74:45:49:ec:
                b6:ca:fd:eb:94:0b:13:0b:cc:0d:2c:a4:45:77:0c:
                07:6f:20:01:9a:21:61:77:fa:3d:6b:3d:4e:6d:ef:
                7d:5a:85:82:9f:11:82:78:70:50:82:97:9d:c6:ae:
                b5:8a:fc:a3:3d:51:db:92:66:70:3d:86:76:f0:95:
                29:cc:20:f4:a5:50:b4:30:82:d7:7b:ff:36:87:90:
                42:63:c9:d0:75:29:7a:7b:a3:78:7d:80:4b:af:19:
                d1:15:90:ff:06:1a:4c:fb:ef:83:ee:56:b9:dd:1f:
                74:9c:e7:d7:7a:11:7e:74:c2:55:e3:3e:86:f5:fe:
                a5:f2:94:3e:21:0a:01:62:0e:a7:7d:32:b6:a5:16:
                e8:cd:46:de:c5:ea:c4:be:88:42:f6:bf:72:75:96:
                a8:82:f4:e1:31:4c:a8:62:ac:54:d2:bc:5c:42:21:
                d9:29:a7:c7:73:a2:12:31:04:bf:37:08:4e:55:2f:
                46:13:d8:0c:4b:8c:73:ad:eb:f1:8a:92:85:c9:22:
                28:04:de:91:71:d6:7f:ca:43:08:ad:f4:72:24:a9:
                f1:e4:12:fa:d8:97:50:e5:a9:9f:91:2d:db:2b:4e:
                90:03
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            35:50:60:0B:18:C6:A4:6C:74:4D:6B:9A:A2:4C:5F:57:16:93:56:60
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:35:50:60:0B:18:C6:A4:6C:74:4D:6B:9A:A2:4C:5F:57:16:93:56:60

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:TRUE
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     46:8f:75:06:48:8c:0a:c6:45:d0:f6:26:99:eb:7a:e2:31:e6:
     4a:76:7f:ba:af:30:ed:d8:04:39:e5:26:94:23:bf:38:1c:28:
     df:1f:d2:63:b7:36:bb:3e:aa:9a:1b:35:c0:db:73:98:5a:6a:
     41:3a:64:6e:53:33:c1:92:63:7c:3a:3a:1e:1c:9b:ed:55:eb:
     dd:eb:cb:50:a4:56:19:46:8f:8b:55:e6:97:0d:b0:53:07:b1:
     e6:8f:4b:6a:a1:ba:dd:d1:1e:14:9a:49:f9:b0:fd:40:0f:e3:
     a5:7f:fd:ab:d3:fc:ff:e0:3d:5c:46:91:f4:b4:7d:fb:56:f6:
     3a:ec:64:ac:18:1b:d5:10:ec:c9:7c:c4:3f:7c:98:4a:80:ed:
     66:84:d8:12:e3:ff:38:9b:03:51:67:89:ba:33:af:88:5c:c4:
     cd:47:e8:3f:46:2a:ee:c4:a3:b7:96:55:23:80:d5:ed:34:ef:
     3c:7c:6c:ad:1b:dc:4d:69:00:27:85:87:f8:96:92:c0:d0:51:
     b4:47:9e:4f:36:d9:70:b7:55:b8:60:bf:99:b7:e3:4d:b0:8c:
     47:8a:d0:a1:41:76:97:d6:dc:a3:a5:43:b4:aa:c3:6c:f1:e9:
     8b:45:7f:a4:9f:e9:73:73:af:49:ed:32:1c:06:fd:f8:23:36:
     22:5b:74:3c
```

netstat -tlpn output

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address              State           PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                        LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                        LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Please provide the virtual host config where the certificate is used.

Comment: Hm. It just occurred to me: Do you even have an (active) `Listen` directive for port 443 somewhere? Is your firewall set to allow incoming connections on port 443?

Comment: @DanielB My 443 is open. Is my SSL virtual host opening tag correct. I have also added a comment regarding what I did according to the answer, below the answer. Still getting similar error on the logs.

Comment: It’s a warning, not an error. It’s irrelevant. Please verify that Apache is listening at port 443, using `netstat -tlpn`.

Comment: @DanielB Ive edited the question and added output from netstat.

Comment: Well, it's definitely not working. I just noticed this is an EC2 VM. Which again brings me to the question: Is port 443 allowed in the firewall? There are two firewalls: iptables inside the VM and the AWS firewall at Amazon.

Comment: @DanielB Yes it is an Amazon EC2 instance. Firewall is inactive when I pass `ufw status`. Iptables -L shows the following. `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination `
And regards to AWS firewall, I have not purchased any firewall from AWS yet.

Comment: You are *always* firewalled by AWS. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: @DanielB thank you for hanging on so far. I added a rule on my network security configuration within my AWS console dashboard to allow https on port 443. This seem to have worked. https://52.24.182.161/
I will post a new answer regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this solved. Big thanks to [@Danel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b). Since I am using an Amazon EC2 instance server, during initial launching of the instance, I didn't configure a rule to https and the rule was only to allow http. So adding a rule on Amazon console's `network and security group`solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the logs:

```
AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

and:

```
AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 52.24.182.161:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

First, you are running a web server.  A web server is an end-entity (an entity that uses certificates) not a certification authority (an entity that manufactures certificates).

Secondly, the DNS name that you enter in your browser must match the name in the certificate.  This will be either the CommonName (CN) or listed in the SubjectAlternateName (SAN) fields.

To fix the first, find out where your OpenSSL configuration file resides, with:

```
$ openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
```

The above is on a Fedora box, therefore the path might be different for you.  In that directory should be a file called `openssl.cnf`.  Edit it with your favourite editor (we all have a favourite apparently) and find the line that says:

```
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE
```

Remove this line, or disable it be prepending a hash (`#`) symbol:

```
#basicConstraints=CA:TRUE
```

That should get rid of the CA certificate error message.

To resolve the second issue, simply make sure that the CommonName (CN) you enter when running OpenSSL is the DNS name (not the URL and do not include https://) that you will be entering in your browser.  There are more complex solutions that involve the SubjectAlternateName, but this one should get your issue fixed.

Comment: IIRC you can't create a self-signed certificate that's not a CA. They aren't errors anyway, but warnings.

Comment: @DanielB - You certainly can create a self-signed certificate without a basicConstraint.  Give it a try :-)  You are right, they are warnings, but the it's difficult to guess what _all_ clients will do when faced with a TLS certificate that claims to be a CA cert too.  Not to mention what the other extensions are set to.

Comment: It’s not difficult at all, actually. It’s not trusted by default and then when you add it, it is.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question and adding the output of the following command: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/apache2/ssl/apache-selfsigned.crt` and your apache config file.

Comment: @DanielB - if `openssl.cnf` is configured as to generate a CA certificate, then there is a possibility (expectation?) that `keyCertSign` and `crlSign` keyUsage extensions are set, as opposed to`digitialSignature` and/or `keyEncipherment`, which should be set for a TLS certificate (depending on the cipher options expected to be used).  If this is the case, a well implemented client should reject the certificate.  It's a little more complex that just adding it.  Of course, they may not be a keyUsage extension, in which case just adding it would work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited the question and added the vhost config where the the certificates are used.

Comment: @garethTheRed - I have also added the output, on the edit.

Comment: @garethTheRed I have done according to your answer but I still get the second error. I do not have a domain name yet. I only have a public IP address. That is what I passed to the common name when running an openssl and still get `RSA certificate configured for 52.24.182.161:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Comment: It might be worth editing your question and adding the output of the following command: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/apache2/ssl/apache-selfsigned.crt` and your apache config file.

Comment: @garethTheRed I have added on the edited question.

Comment: Is that the correct certificate? `CN=sgurung` as opposed to CN being the IP address.  Also, `CA:TRUE` is still set.

Comment: About AH01906: I don't comment the line, having `basicConstraints=CA:FALSE` (default value, Debian 9) should be enough, but is not, still have those warnings on error.log. I'm using let's encrypt (EFF certbot 0.22.2).